# Flutter manipulate Strings

Tags: string, flutter

I am trying to understand flutter and build a test app. In my app should be a row with following output:

> Max Smith, John Travolta, Sarah Conner

I have a list with following entries:

> [Max Smith, John Travolta, Sarah Conner]

I came up with this method:

```
Widget friendsList(){
      return new Wrap(children:
      marked_friends.map((item) =>
      new Text(item + ", ")).toList()
      );
    }
```

After calling the method following row is displayed in my app:

> May Smith, John Travolta, Sarah Conner,

Any idea on how to remove the comma at the end?

Best regards

Comment: Could you show us your `Profile` class?

Comment: I solved it right in this second :) Thanks anyway! Just the problem with the comma at the end of the row is remaining... Any idea on that? Do you still need my Profile class for that? Curly braces and profiles are removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to check, whether the current item is the last item in your list:

`Text(item + (marked_friends.last == item ? '' : ', '))).toList()`

The full code snippet would look like:

```
return Wrap(
    children: marked_friends
        .map((item) => Text(item + (marked_friends.last == item ? '' : ', ')))
        .toList());
```

I also removed the unnecessary new statements ;)

Source: [Ternary (?) Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: With your solution nothing but a single comma is displayed... Not a single item, just a comma.

Comment: Sorry, there were missing some braces :D I've edited the post.